# Append line numbers to selected lines in sed

Tags: sed

I have a corrupted email with the same name "priloha" for many attachments.

```
--=_6307cd41740728f4463731ed=a0cf2ceb-1b64-55a3-9dc3-738b8e19552b_=
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
name=priloha
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
size=50103;
filename=priloha

tABRRRQB/9k=
--=_6307cd41740728f4463731ed=a0cf2ceb-1b64-55a3-9dc3-738b8e19552b_=
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
name=priloha
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
size=59445;
filename=priloha
```

I need to append to the word "priloha" either the line number or 
to modify lines with the word "priloha" in this way:

```
name=priloha23
filename=priloha34
name=priloha134
filename=priloha145
```

and many more lines like this while of course keeping the lines in between.

The numbers can be any unique identifiers, so say line numbers.

I have a working following script:

```
sed 's/\r//g' input.eml >output.eml # dos end of lines into unix ones
for i in {10..50} # cca 30 attachments to procede 
 do
  sed -i "0,/name=priloha$/s//name=priloha$i/"        output.eml
  sed -i "0,/filename=priloha$/s//filename=priloha$i/"  output.eml
 done
```

You would presumably admit it is sort of clumsy.
Can you give me a hit how make it in one run.
Something like this:

sed "/name=priloha/s/name=priloha/name=priloha[current line #]/" input.eml > output.eml # not working

Expectation: find lines with "name=priloha" change it into "name=priloha[current line #]"

I am looking forward to your smart ideas and thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please do check my solution and lemme know if that helped you?

Comment: Dear Mr. Ravinder, yes it is an excelent solution, that I am not able to invent. That is what I like on Linux - it is run by people who really love computers. :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/priloha/=' file && sed -Ei 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*priloha)/\2\1/;P;D' file
```

The first sed invocation inserts the line number of the line containing the word `priloha` into the file. The second invocation, appends the line number to the word `priloha`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, in case you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/priloha/,"&"FNR)} 1'  Input_file
```

This will substitute string `priloha` with string and line string and line number.

Once you are ok with above command(which prints output on terminal) and in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

```
awk '{sub(/priloha/,"&"FNR)} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: I have nothing against awk, it is simpler via AWK, but the question was, how to do it in sed, so I flagged the previous question as the correct one. But both are working like a charm. Thanks! Post Scriptum. I have to pay more attention to awk, as I see... :-)

Comment: @xerostomus, np at all, I am glad that we could help you, cheers and happy learning.